# Filezilla - App keeps crashing when double clicking a folder Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, desktop-environments, filezilla

Recently Filezilla been messing with me. It keeps on crashing when i open the folder within my sftp connection. The app opens fine, i can connect with my sftp settings fine but when I open the folder, it crashes. How to fix? I can't find a solution online matching my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not the only one with this problem, as seen in the FileZilla forums:

https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=45830

The only solutions are either to wait until an upgraded version is available in your repository, or use the Linux package provided on the FileZilla website.